# How to continue using the online banking feature of GnuCash (AqBanking) with PSD2 in effect?

Tags: gnucash, online-banking, regulation

I'm running GnuCash 2.6.19 (with AqBanking 5.7.8.0) on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.

Ever since the European Commission's [Revised Directive on Payment Services (PSD2)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_Services_Directive#Revised_Directive_on_Payment_Services_(PSD2)) came into effect online banking with the above no longer works.

Apparently, there is a [newer version of AqBanking (5.99.25beta)](https://www.aquamaniac.de/rdm/projects/aqbanking/wiki/PSD2) which supports [Strong Customer Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_customer_authentication). However, that new version is still in beta and apart from some mentions on https://www.aquamaniac.de/rdm/ there hardly seems to be anything written or reviewed about it. Also, it will probably take light-years until this update reaches official Ubuntu repositories :(

*Now I'm aware this "question" may not (yet) be a "good" one (by the standards of StackExchange); but it's a big topic and it's kind of silly that the directive effectively "broke" my ability to feed my books and bank statements in GnuCash with data from my bank:*

- **How to continue using the online banking feature of GnuCash (AqBanking) with  PSD2 in effect?**
- Can anyone report that (s)he's been able to get **online banking in GnuCash** up and running again (after encountering hitherto unseen errors about "two-factor authentication" failing)?

---

Related links:

- https://hilfe.starmoney.de/hc/de/articles/360025932554-Was-ist-die-PSD2-und-was-bedeutet-sie-f%C3%BCr-StarMoney-
- https://hilfe.starmoney.de/hc/de/articles/360025618373-Kann-ich-mein-ING-Girokonto-trotz-PSD2-weiter-%C3%BCber-StarMoney-f%C3%BChren-

Comment: AQfinance has released a beta that supports PSD2. Unfortunately, I do not know how to integrate them into GnuCash, so I depend on the developers. So it would be great if they could integrate the new version into Gnucash. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

With the new versions Gwenhywfar 4.99.16beta, AqBanking 5.99.32beta und Gnucash 3.7 it is working again.

I found the solution at the thread https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/post/9099928/

Have a look at the PPA https://launchpad.net/~ingo/+archive/ubuntu/gnucash/
which is compiled ready for ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Thanks, there was missing some characters in the link. I corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

[Ubuntu 19.10 (Eoan Ermine)](https://itsfoss.com/ubuntu-19-10-release-feature/) will be released in ~ 10 days time from now and it looks like it's going to include the [latest version of GnuCash](https://www.gnucash.org/download.phtml) (3.7, as of today), cf.:

- https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gnucash (**eoan**: 1:**3.7**-1ubuntu1)
- https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/eoan/+package/gnucash (gnucash 1:**3.7**-1ubuntu1)

which is, however, contradicted by

- https://wiki.gnucash.org/wiki/Ubuntu#Ubuntu_19.10_.28.22Eoan_Ermine.22.29 ("GnuCash **3.4** is included in Ubuntu **19.10**")

We shall soon see what and who's right… If 19.10 will indeed ship with the latest version of GnuCash (and AqBanking !) then that might solve the problem :-) To be confirmed…

---

**Update:**

Just installed 19.10 and can confirm it shipped with GnuCash 3.7, build 2019-09-07, and AqBanking 5.8.2-0.1 (cf. https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/gnucash and https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/libaqbanking35), which seems to be, as expected, prior to the beta mentioned above :(

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [**GnuCash** added support for **Flatpak**](https://www.gnucash.org/download.phtml):

[image]

Comment: https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/10/new-website-claims-flatpak-is-a-security-nightmare