# GnuCash with (optical) PhotoTAN?

Tags: gnucash, online-banking

With Ubuntu 20.04.1 I now installed GnuCash - both as Flatpak (version 4.1) and from the official repos (version 3.8) and am nothing less than flabbergasted that [online banking still won't just work again](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/114571/how-to-continue-using-the-online-banking-feature-of-gnucash-aqbanking-with-psd). With 2-factor-authentification, **I'm being prompted for the PhotoTAN without being presented an image to scan**. There's a [Python script](https://git.uniku.de/sven/phototan-for-gnucash/-/tree/master) which was last updated about a year ago to presumable tackle that issue. There are hints to the fact that the sandboxed Flatpak installation might need [some extra tweaks to display the PNG](https://www.koecher.it/doku.php?id=projects:projektuebersicht#foto_tan_verfahren_bei_der_comdirect).

I don't mind if its version 3.8 or 4.1. I just want online banking back. Any guidance much appreciated (or at least encouragement to try and use either the abandoned (?) Python script or the sandbox tweaking).

What a bummer.

Comment: https://ostechnix.com/how-to-display-images-in-the-terminal/